# What is the sessionstate mode if I dont mention sessionstate tag in my web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-state

I recently moved into a new project and when I was trying to inspect the sessionstate used in the application I was shocked to see no `sessionstate` tag in web.config file of the web application.

What would be the default sessionstate in this case? would it be `InProc` or does it mean that we cannot use sessions in this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the default sessionstate is  `InProc mode`

`InProc mode` stores session state in memory on the Web server.

and you can use other `sessionstate`  for many other propose..

you can use `stateserver mode`  , `SQLServer mode`.

You can also disable the session of the web application using `off mode`

Comment: and it doesn't mean that you cant use sessions in this application